# Does anyone know how to create a paypal donate button using flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create an app using Flutter that will have a Paypal donate button, but Paypal only gives html code for their donate button, so does anyone know how to create is using Flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own button with a `Container - decoration - radius`, a background color and so on (or just an image with a `FlatButton` on top), but that is not recommended.
`App Store Guidelines` prohibit any third party payment solutions. So you could only use it in the Play Store with Android Apps.

Now what you can do is use In-App Purchases to handle such donations. There is an easy package [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_iap).

Set everything like in the example and just call this to start a purchase flow:

```
List<IAPProduct> _productIds = [];
...
@override initState() { 
    super.initState(); 
    init(); 
} 

init() async { 
    IAPResponse response = await FlutterIap.fetchProducts(["com.example.testiap"]); 
    List<IAPProduct> productIds = response.products; 
    if (!mounted) 
        return; 
    setState(() {
        _productIds = productIds; 
    }); 
}
```

Then call this, anywhere you like:

`FlutterIap.buy(_productIds.first.productIdentifier);`

Comment: What if we're using flutter only for website, in that case how Paypal donate button can be added?

Comment: Personally not inclined to use a third party package (that could be hacked without me noticing) to handle payments